# No genera tabla temporal SQL desde C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Estoy trabajando con C# y SQL, trato de crear una tabla temporal desde C# pero mi código no me genera mi tabla temporal en BD SQL, si hago la creacion con una tabla normal si me permite, no se como se podria crear

```html
string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr90"].ConnectionString;

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE  #test([CDSN] VARCHAR(20))";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                con.Open();

                try
                {
                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Cierro la Conexión.
                    con.Close();
                }
```

Comment: El codigo debe ir como texto

Comment: eh.. estas seguro que no se crea?? o se crea en esaa conexion, y como cerras la conexion se pierde???? que seria sql??? proque sql es un lenguaje, no una base de datos....